# how to extract formula in their actual form from wikipedia to python

Tags: python

I have a python program where I am printing the Wikipedia summary.

```
def OnEnter(self, event):    
    input = self.txt.GetValue()    
    input = input.lower()               
    print wikipedia.summary(input)
```

I want to make the program to narrate the summary immediately after printing for the user. How can I do that?
As also how can I extract formula in their actual form from wikipedia to python

Comment: Can you share a pseudo code of what you would like to do?

Comment: My code let me ask any question, suppose "Who is edison", then the result comes in text form like "Thomas Alva Edison (February 11, 1847 – October 18, 1931) was an American inventor and businessman, who has been described as America's greatest inventor. He developed many devices that greatly influenced life around the world, including the phonograph, the motion picture camera, and the long-lasting, practical electric light bulb." from Wikipedia summery. I want this resulted text to be spoken. is there any way to do this?

Comment: and also if I ask "what is ohms law" it answers "Ohm's law states that the current through a conductor between two points is directly proportional to the voltage across the two points. Introducing the constant of proportionality, the resistance, the relationship:        
      
        I    
        =    
        
          
            V    
            R    
          
        
        ,
      
    
    {\displaystyle I={\frac {V}{R}},}". see the formula is not is its regular shape. what should i do to turn it into its regular shape?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use pyttsx as described in https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/text-to-speech/ .

For the next part, as your formulas will be rendered in latex. So try to Google about how latex formula can be converted to text from in python. There are some answers regarding this. I don't know what you want exactly as the end result. So not quoting those here. Just Google and see.

Hope it helps.